# How to display list items correctly in my paginated views

Tags: grails, controller, pagination, view

This controller will list all games from my database.

```
def index() {
    def platform = gameService.listPlatform()
    def max = params.max ?: 10
    def offset = params.offset ?: 0
    def chosenPlatfrm = params.platform
    def taskList = gameService.listGamePlat(chosenPlatfrm,max,offset)
    def taskL = gameService.whatsHot(chosenPlatfrm,max,offset)
    [games:taskL, bb:taskList, chosenPlatform:chosenPlatfrm, platforms:platform, gameCount:taskL.totalCount, gameCont:taskList.totalCount] 

}
```

This is how my index.gsp looks.

```
<g:each in="${games}" status="i" var="game">
        <g:if test="${game.averageRating != 0 }">
            <g:link action="gameProfile"
                params="${[gameTitle: "${game.gameTitle}"]}">
            </g:link>
        </g:if>
</g:each>
<div class="pagination" style="text-align: center;">
        <g:paginate action="index" total="${gameCount}" offset="0" max="3" params="${params.max}"/>
</div>
```

I want to limit my paginated view into only 3 items every page. When index.gsp receives data from my index controller it will displays everything in my list even though i have a pagination tag, but when i clicked a page number it seems to be working fine.

I tried redirect in my index controller but it displays an error "Error redirect loop"

```
 redirect(action: "index", params:[id:'',offset: '0', max: '3'])
```

How will i display my index.gsp correctly?

Comment: Can't you try same by first generating generate-view script and then modifying it accordingly.

Comment: its fixed now. i just did some if statement when controller calls index.gsp for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem is in view. Try:

```
<g:paginate total="${gameCount}" />
```

instead of:

```
<g:paginate action="index" total="${gameCount}" offset="0" max="3" params="${params.max}"/>
```

Another problem is in controller: you should write another function to count **gameCount** variable, which will count number all of games in every paginated view (so without offset and limit parameter).

Of course redirect is wrong because you are executing controller's index() function over and over and over again, so stay with the first provided code.

Comment: this is fixed. i just put some if statement where it will display 3 items when controller calls index for the first time. Pagination is handled correctly when i clicked the number pages .